# _imaging C module error in python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I have read the other posts about the notorious _imaging C module error when installing PIL on Mac OS X and none of the solutions provided anywhere, including the PIL FAQ, have proven helpful.

I have the newest versions of libjpeg and zlib freshly installed from source. I have edited the Makefiles in each of these to include the option -arch i386 in the LD_FLAGS variable for 32-bit builds. PIL installs with no problems of any kind and the install summary printed to the terminal says that JPEG, TIFF, and PNG support are all OK. After that I try the self test:

```
new-host:Imaging-1.1.7 ely$ python selftest.py 
*** The _imaging C module is not installed
```

This is commonly seen for a variety of reasons. Probing deeper, here I try to import _imaging directly in python.

```
new-host:Imaging-1.1.7 ely$ python
ActivePython 2.7.1.4 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb  7 2011, 11:33:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
>>> import _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Here again, the 'Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart' is notorious and common, and many people have suggested this has to do with incorrect path to libjpeg. I've checked again and again and I only have libjpeg (as well as zlib, etc.) installed in my home directory, all in separate folders, from source, and all of this is marked correctly in the file setup.py.

So, PIL should be getting its jpeg support (and zlib, etc.) from the right places. All the dependencies are installed. I can see _imaging.so in my sys.path, yet I still get this _jpeg_resync_to_restart error.

Are there any ideas that don't link to alternate posts? I have spent ~7 hours reading and trying possible solutions from posts in every forum I can find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have been trying this a few times, I recommend running a few commands to clean out the old items first and start from the beginning.

I used jpeg v8c and Imaging 1.1.6 on Mac OS X, 10.6 and 10.7

get v8c of jpeg
cd into jpeg directory.

```
sudo make clean
CC="gcc -arch i386" ./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
```

get imaging i am using 1.1.6

untar
cd into imaging

```
sudo rm -rf build
vi setup.py
JPEG_ROOT = libinclude(“/usr/local/lib”)
sudo python setup.py install
```

And it’s that simple

Run your python interpreter,

```
import PIL
import _imaging
import Image
```

if all is well, then your all set.

Here is the full article on my blog [Python 2.7, OSX Lion, PIL and Imaging](http://appelfreelance.com/2011/07/python-2-7-os-x-lion-and-pil-_imaging-and-image/)

Comment: Appel, thank you for this recipe. On 10.7.1 with stock python 2.7.1 it works until the "import _imaging" : Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart  


Neither using JPEG_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/local") as stated here : http://proteus-tech.com/blog/cwt/install-pil-in-snow-leopard/

Comment: If I might ask you one question, what source are you using? zshrc, bash? make sure that the first line on your PATH is /usr/local/bin

Comment: when you "echo $PATH" what is the output?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/Users/dom/django/libs/homebrew/bin:/Users/dom/django/libs/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Developer/Tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Developer/Tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: Mine looks as follows, notice how "/usr/local/bin" is first - /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/sw2/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/8.4.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

I had the same issues, long time ago until I did a lot of reading, your /usr/local/bin should be first, that way your applications installed are always looking to that path first, hence why changing the JPEG_ROOT is not being picked up.

Comment: I got such error when trying to import _imaging:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so 

WHAT CAN BE THE REASON? HOW TO DEAL WITH IT?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem this evening on my mac running Mac OS X v10.7.5, Python v2.7.1 with PIL Imaging 1.1.7 and jpeg 8d.

---

#### Summarizing - the key to success in my case was:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

---

Nothing from the other answers have solved the issue, constantly I've been getting:
`The _imaging C module is not installed` caused by: 
`Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart`.

Digging here and there finally I've found the solution, at least works for me:

- ensure you don't have any obvious libjpeg libs on the system: `find / -iname "libjpe*"` will tell you that. I have temporarily changed places where they exist so no one could find them (especially /sw was interacting with PIL in my case):

  ```
  mv opt opt-OFF  
  mv sw sw-OFF
  ```

These locations have been created by mac ports and fink - be warned that it is quite possible that `FREETYPE2` might not be found by PIL after this move - if you need it, then just rename libjpeg parts in those locations.

- in PIL Imaging src directory edit setup.py as described above to set JPEG_ROOT to /usr/local, try to run:

  ```
  rm -rf build ; python setup.py build 2> /tmp/err > /tmp/log
  ```

Check in /tmp/log - you should *not* see JPEG support available. You can now go to the next step.

- go to jpeg-8d src directory and run:

  ```
  export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"  
  sudo make clean; CC="gcc -arch x86_64" ./configure --enable-shared --enable-static  
  sudo make install
  ```
- go back to PIL Imaging, run these commands:

  ```
  export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"  
  sudo rm -rf build ; python setup.py build 2> /tmp/err > /tmp/log
  ```

Check in /tmp/log - you should now see "JPEG support available", check /tmp/err - search for "jpeg" - if you see something like this:
`ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)` - then the arch flags (both set by ARCHFLAGS and -arch) failed to trigger - investigate that case, it is crucial. If you don't see this, then you're lucky and you can invoke the installation:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"  
sudo rm -rf build ; sudo python setup.py install
```

Check if your PIL works:

```
python selftest.py
```

or

```
echo "import _imaging" | python && echo "Works"
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the _imaging module is linked to libjpeg *dynamically*, not statically. The libjpeg code is not included in the _imaging module directly. This means that your platform's dynamic linker has to be able to find libjpeg in order to load and link it. My MacOS knowledge here is fuzzy, but as I recall its dynamic linker is called `dyld`, and its manpage may provide more information on the options you have.

Normally, the platform's dynamic linker won't be looking in your homedirectory for libraries -- but you can tell it to, for example by setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, or editing the system-wide configuration (if there is one.) Setting that environment variable usually has to be done before you start Python, though, so it may not be suitable. You may want to try to embed the runtime search path into the _imaging extension module, which is usually done by passing `-rpath` to the linker -- but I don't know if MacOS's linker offers that capability. Finally, you can just build libjpeg as a *static* library, instead of a shared one, and have the _imaging module link against that. That would avoid the whole shared library situation for libjpeg. For libjpeg, this is probably done by running its `configure` script with `--enable-static --disable-shared`.

Comment: I'm trying to work on some of your suggestions. I re-compiled libjpeg with the two options you mentioned, then recompiled PIL but still get the same error. I thought perhaps zlib needs a similar static build, but when I do 'configure --static' for zlib, the corresponding call to 'sudo make install' fails, and it seems to be an error with the makefiles. The makefiles actually invoke an incorrect call to the 'cp' command, as if when --static is on, it tries to copy a non-existent file.

Comment: Just to add, when I do the compile of PIL, and the summary prints out, it says that JPEG and PNG support are OK, meaning that it must be correctly locating libjpeg and zlib.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many most all of these suggestions (as well as two other suggestions on referenced blogs) on an old 10.6 Mac install. None of them worked as-is, however, reading behind the lines I was able to fix my problem. I added to the PIL setup.py in find_include_file() right before the return 1 line "print os.path.join(directory, include)". This allowed me to track down which libjpeg PIL is building against. Then I would build PIL, find the libjpeg it referenced (various copies in /sw, /opt/, /usr/local/lib, ...), and delete that libjpeg (both header and lib files).

Finally with a clean system I built and installed libjpeg source tarball that I'd downloaded myself, followed by building and installing PIL from source. This worked. As a fallback you could always *disable* libjpeg by removing the above files as described or else always returning zero from the described above function in setup.py.

Answer (score 1):

Works well for me on Mountain Lion 10.8.2:

**Step One**. Removing all jpeg packages. For MacPorts:

`sudo port -f uninstall jpeg` or `sudo port -f uninstall jpeg @version_here`

We need to remove *all* jpeg versions!

**Step Two**. Remove PIL: `pip uninstall PIL`

**Step Three**. Install jpeg package again. For MacPorts: `sudo port install jpeg`

**Step Four**. Install PIL again: `pip install PIL`

```
>>> import PIL
>>> import _imaging
```

No errors!

---

**How to remove ALL jpeg packages?**

```
$ port installed | grep -i jpeg
jpeg @8c_0
jpeg @9a_0 (active)

$ sudo port -f uninstall jpeg @8c_0
$ sudo port -f uninstall jpeg @9a_0
```

Don't care about dependies. Beacause we need to install jpeg package again:

```
$ sudo port install jpeg
```

Comment: your soltion is not working. Still get: ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so

Answer (score 1):

I ran into all the errors you guys have mentioned. I broke down and just used virtualenv and installed Pillow instead. it worked:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv python_script && cd !$
. /activate/bin
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with Python 2.7 and OSX Lion, and basically followed @ApPeL process and re-installed libjpeg and PIL. libjpeg seemed to be installed correctly, and PIL seemed to find it correctly, but running `python -v` and then `import _imaging` gave always this error:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart

After installing and re-installing libjpeg (version 8d) and PIL (version 1.1.7) twenty times with slightly different options, what did the trick was making sure I removed all libjpeg files under **/usr/local/include** (headers), as well as the files under /user/local/lib.

I didn't need to install PIL from source, I used `pip install pil`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me-
http://www.thetoryparty.com/2010/08/31/pil-on-snow-leopard-_jpeg_resync_to_restart-error/

Answer (score 0):

I have been attempting to install PIL (OS X 10.7.5, Python 2.7.3) for about 5 hours. I too have been bogged down with the 'Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart" error and have tried many of the proposed solutions to no avail, including reinstalling all of its dependencies. Finally, I discovered a double-clickable installation of [Pillow](https://code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/detail?name=pillow-1.7.7-0.pkg&can=2&q=).

Thank you Rudix! Now "import PIL" and "import _imaging" work!

p.s. I had installed libjpeg [via](http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html) i didn't specifically delete this install, so I'm not sure if this was part of the final solution or not.